# Image view vertical paging android

Tags: android, native, vertical-scroll

I am new for android developer. I need to build image view to my apps . Here is the library that i used.
https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

Everything is working good. Here is my question is it possible make it to vertical paging?  Instead of swipe left or right to pagging. Please guide me some example also.

Thanks

Comment: Everything in Android is fully customizable, you just need to figure out how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the parent to the `PhotoView` library is a `ViewPager`, which is, as you say, horizontally aligned. There's not native VerticalViewPager, but there are examples of customized solutions that devs have come up with for this. [Here's](http://shashikaonline.com/2013/06/26/creating-a-simple-vertical-viewpager-in-android/) and example of one build from a `ScrollView`. As a simpler first step you could even try swapping over to the native `ScrollView` as your parent view and then customize from there.